# Generic method to update different data type properties in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I don't if its possible or not, but I think there can be a way to do what I want.
I have following situation:

```
enum ContactStatus: UInt {
    case requestSent = 0, requestReceived, requestProcessing, active, removed
}

struct Contact {
    var uid: String
    var name: String?
    var contactStatus: ContactStatus

    init(uid: String, name: String? = nil, contactStatus: ContactStatus = .requestSent) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.name = name
        self.contactStatus = contactStatus
    }
}

class ContactStorage: {
    private var contacts: [Contact]
    init(contacts: [Contact]) {
        contacts = contacts
    }

    func createContact(uid: String, contactStatus status: ContactStatus, name: String?) -> Contact {
        var newContact = Contact(uid: uid)
        newContact.contactStatus = status
        newContact.name = name
        newContacts.append(newContact)
        return newContact
    }
    func updateContact(status: ContactStatus, peerUId: String) {
        for (index, _) in contacts.enumerated() {
            if contacts[index].uid == peerUId {
                contacts[index].contactStatus = status
                return
            }
        }
    }
    func updateContact(name: String, peerUId: String) {
        for (index, _) in contacts.enumerated() {
            if contacts[index].uid == peerUId {
                contacts[index].name = name
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As we can see, `ContactStorage` has two methods to update contact status and name.
I am looking to merge these two methods in one using generic data types or any other possible way.

Something like:

```
func updateContact<T: Updateable>(peerUId: String, updatableProperty: T) {
    //implementation
}
```

Is it possible to write only one method instead of two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "kind of" do this with closures.

The "XXX" and "YYY" part is the only part that is different between the two methods you have:

```
for (index, _) in contacts.enumerated() {
    if contacts[index].uid == peerUId {
        contacts[index].XXX = YYY
        return
    }
}
```

So, if we want to extract this as a method, we need a closure as parameter to provide the "XXX" part.

That closure can look like this:

```
(inout Contact, T) -> Void
```

For the "YYY" part, a regular parameter will do just fine.

So, the method looks like this:

```
func updateProperty<T>(property: (inout Contact, T) -> Void, value: T, peerUId: String) {
    for (index, _) in contacts.enumerated() {
        if contacts[index].uid == peerUId {
            property(&contacts[index], value)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
updateProperty(property: {$0.name = $1}, value: "Tom", peerUId: "something")
```

Another way to do this is to remove "YYY" completely, and integrate it into the closure:

```
func updateProperty(property: (inout Contact) -> Void, peerUId: String) {
    for (index, _) in contacts.enumerated() {
        if contacts[index].uid == peerUId {
            property(&contacts[index])
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
updateProperty(property: {$0.name = "Tom"}, peerUId: "something")
```

Comment: ERROR: `$0` is immutable

Comment: @D4ttatraya Oops! Didn't notice Contact is a struct. Corrected now.

Comment: Removing 'YYY' completely is really clever and cleaner way

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a generic function. You should just make `updateContact` have 3 input arguments: `peerUId`, `name` and `status` and set the latter two to be optionals with a  `nil` default value. This way you can update both `name` and `status` using a single function call and if you only want to update one of them, you just don't specify an input value for the other.

```
func updateContact(peerUId: String, status: ContactStatus? = nil, name: String? = nil) {
    if status == nil, name == nil { return } //wrong function call, return
    for i in 0..<contacts.count {
        if contacts[i].uid == peerUId {
            if let newStatus = status {
                contacts[i].contactStatus = newStatus
            }
            if let newName = name {
                contacts[i].name = newName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can call the function like this:

```
updateContact(peerUId: "value", status: ContactStatus.active) //only updates the contactStatus

updateContact(peerUId: "value", name: "John") //only updates the name

updateContact(peerUId: "value", status: ContactStatus.active, name: "John") //updates both in a single function call
```